# What heirlooms to get for a DPS Death Knight?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am slightly confused with what heirlooms to get if I want to play a DPS based death knight. I'd like to equip first for full exp gain followed by whatever will help me produce the most DPS. I plan on getting as many heirloom (delta the ring as it's really a pain to win) before I start playing the DK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're a DPS you should get these:

[Polished Spaulders of Valor](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42949)
[Polished Breastplate of valor](http://www.wowhead.com/item=48685)
[Worn Stoneskin Gargoyle Cape](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62038)
[Polished Helm of Valor](http://www.wowhead.com/item=61931)

You can get the first two with Justice Points in Orgrimmar/Stormwind from the [Justice Heirloom vendor](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=justice+heirlooms) or in Dalaran from the [Heirloom vendors](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=heirloom+vendor).

The cape and the helm are available from the [Guild vendor](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=guild+vendor) once your guild has reached a high enough level (10 for the cape, 20 for the helm)

Adding a [Bloodied Arcanite Reaper](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42943) to the mix may be a good idea: it may lack the experience bonus, but you get a good weapon that scales with your level.

All of the above would provide you a nice 35% bonus experience (until level 80, at which point spaulders and chestplate stop to work) and a good boost to your stats, scaling gracefully while you level.

If you still have Justice points in excess you can also get the [Swift Hand of Justice](http://www.wowhead.com/item=42991): not a great improvement when compared to the other heirlooms, but a little haste and a self heal can help from time to time.

As Adanion pointed out in the comments an alternative way to get your Heirlooms is from [Dame Evniki Kapsalis](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=34885/dame-evniki-kapsalis) at the [Argent Tournament](http://www.wowpedia.org/Argent_Tournament).

You'll need [Champion's Seals](http://www.wowhead.com/item=44990) to buy items from her, which are a reward from the dailies in the zone.

This area is not current content anymore, since it's been released in Wrath of the Lich King, and it takes days of work to unlock all of the dailies available.

It can be anyway a good source if you have nothing to do except waiting for the next Heroic to pop up. In the event you already unlocked the Tournament and you have many 80+ character it can even become quite profitable, since Heirlooms are bound to account and you can move them between your toons.

Comment: You can also purchase all of the PvE heirlooms from [Dame Evniki Kapsalis](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=34885) at the Argent Tournament in Icecrown. If you have all of the dailies unlocked it will take you just over 3 days per chest and shoulder piece, and just over 5 days for most weapons. If I don't feel like grinding Justice points and are not in a hurry this option works great. I just take four or five of my characters out there daily and will get the whole set of heirlooms and trinkets in about 5 days. This option probably wont be worth it for people that didn't play during Wrath.

Comment: @Adanion you're right. I didn't add the Argent Tournament in my answer though because you have to go a long way out of your way to get there. Since it's not current content anymore means you have to get there on purpose, and some of those quests, even if easy, take a long time to get completed. I'll edit my answer anyway for completeness sake.

Comment: I can agree with the extra time and travel. I personally have A full server of max level characters some of which are just for gathering, quest grinding, etc. I just leave these characters out there in the tent and I would log on to them to do the quests. With epic flying, and assuming you don't get either of the quests that send you to Storm Peaks, you should be able to finish all the quests and get 18 tokens in less than 20 mins.